# QGraphicsView: repaint one item when another item is modified

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

In a QGraphicsView I use two elements: states and connectors.

I add two states, and then I create a connector. I pass to the connector the pointers of two states in order to calculate start and end point. Something like that:

[image: creation]

The problem is when I drag one of two states. I want that the connector is updated as well. At the moment the position remain unchanged:

[image: moved stated]

This is my state class:

```
class SimpleStateShape : public QGraphicsObject{

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  enum { Type = UserType + SimpleStateType };

public:

  SimpleStateShape(QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr);
  virtual ~SimpleStateShape();

public:

  QRectF boundingRect() const override;
  void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget) override;
  int type() const override;

private:

  Style::CanvasSimpleState m_style; // It contains style like pens and brushes, not important here
  QSize m_size;
};

////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PUBLIC SECTION                                                            //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

SimpleStateShape::SimpleStateShape(QGraphicsItem* parent) :
  QGraphicsObject(parent),
  m_size(style.getMinimumSize()) {
  setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemContainsChildrenInShape);
}

SimpleStateShape::~SimpleStateShape() {

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// VIRTUAL PUBLIC SECTION                                                    //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

QRectF SimpleStateShape::boundingRect() const {
  qreal penWidth = m_style.getContourPen().widthF();
  qreal x = -(m_size.width() + penWidth) * 0.5;
  qreal y = -(m_size.height() + penWidth) * 0.5;
  return QRectF(x, y, m_size.width(), m_size.height());
}

void SimpleStateShape::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget) {
  qreal penWidth = m_style.getContourPen().widthF();
  qreal x = -(m_size.width() + penWidth) * 0.5;
  qreal y = -(m_size.height() + penWidth) * 0.5;
  QRectF boundingRect(x, y, m_size.width(), m_size.height());
  painter->setPen(m_style.getContourPen());
  painter->setBrush(m_style.getBackgroundBrush());
  painter->drawRoundedRect(boundingRect, m_style.getCornerRadius(), m_style.getCornerRadius(), Qt::AbsoluteSize);
  painter->drawText(boundingRect, Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter, getName().c_str());
}

int SimpleStateShape::type() const {
  return Type;
}
```

And this is my connector:

```
class TransitionLine : public QGraphicsObject {

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  enum { Type = UserType + TransitionLineType };

public:

  TransitionLine(QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr);
  virtual ~TransitionLine();
  void setStartState(SimpleStateShape* shape);
  void setEndState(SimpleStateShape* shape);
  void showModifiers(bool flag);
  void setSceneControlAnchorPosition(const QPointF& pos);

public:

  QRectF boundingRect() const override;
  QPainterPath shape() const override;
  void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget) override;
  int type() const override;

private:

  void createSubShapes();
  void drawArrow(QPainter* painter);
  void setDefaultLineData();
  void enableModifiers(bool enabled);
  QPointF findRectLineIntersection(const QRectF& rect, const QPointF& p) const;

private:

  Style::CanvasTransition m_style;
  SimpleStateShape* m_startState;
  SimpleStateShape* m_endState;
  QPointF m_firstControlPoint;
  QPointF m_startPoint;
  QPointF m_endPoint;
  QGraphicsEllipseItem* m_controlAnchor;
  QGraphicsLineItem* m_startControlLine;
  QGraphicsLineItem* m_endControlLine;
  bool m_isNew;
  bool m_modifiersEnabled;
};

////////////

TransitionLine::TransitionLine(QGraphicsItem* parent) :
  QGraphicsObject(parent),
  m_startState(nullptr),
  m_endState(nullptr),
  m_isNew(true),
  m_modifiersEnabled(false) {
  createSubShapes();
  setBoundingRegionGranularity(BoundingRegionGranularity);
  setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
  setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
  setZValue(TransitionZValue);
}

TransitionLine::~TransitionLine() {
  int i = 0;
}

void TransitionLine::setStartState(SimpleStateShape* shape) {
  m_startState = shape;
}

void TransitionLine::setEndState(SimpleStateShape* shape) {
  m_endState = shape;
}

void TransitionLine::showModifiers(bool show) {
  enableModifiers(show);
}

void TransitionLine::setSceneControlAnchorPosition(const QPointF& pos) {
  m_firstControlPoint = pos;
  prepareGeometryChange();
  update(boundingRect());
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// VIRTUAL PUBLIC SECTION                                                    //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

QRectF TransitionLine::boundingRect() const {
  if (m_startState == nullptr || m_endState == nullptr) {
    return QRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
  }
  QPointF startStatScenePos = m_startState->scenePos();
  QPointF endStateScenePos = m_endState->scenePos();
  QPointF firstControlScenePos = mapToScene(m_firstControlPoint);
  qreal minX = std::min({ startStatScenePos.x(), endStateScenePos.x(), firstControlScenePos.x() });
  qreal minY = std::min({ startStatScenePos.y(), endStateScenePos.y(), firstControlScenePos.y() });
  qreal maxX = std::max({ startStatScenePos.x(), endStateScenePos.x(), firstControlScenePos.x() });
  qreal maxY = std::max({ startStatScenePos.y(), endStateScenePos.y(), firstControlScenePos.y() });
  return mapRectFromScene(QRectF(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY));
}

QPainterPath TransitionLine::shape() const {
  QPainterPath path;
  path.moveTo(m_startPoint);
  path.quadTo(m_firstControlPoint, m_endPoint);
  QPainterPathStroker stroker;
  stroker.setWidth(StrokeWidth);
  return stroker.createStroke(path).simplified();
}

void TransitionLine::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget) {
  if (m_startState == nullptr || m_endState == nullptr) {
    return;
  }
  if (m_isNew) {
    setDefaultLineData();
    m_isNew = false;
  }
  auto startBB = m_startState->sceneBoundingRect();
  auto endBB = m_endState->sceneBoundingRect();
  painter->setPen(m_style.getLinePen());
  QPainterPath path;
  path.moveTo(m_startPoint);
  path.quadTo(m_firstControlPoint, m_endPoint);
  painter->drawPath(path);
  if (m_modifiersEnabled) {
    m_controlAnchor->setPos(m_firstControlPoint);
    m_startControlLine->setLine(m_startPoint.x(), m_startPoint.y(), m_firstControlPoint.x(), m_firstControlPoint.y());
    m_endControlLine->setLine(m_endPoint.x(), m_endPoint.y(), m_firstControlPoint.x(), m_firstControlPoint.y());
  }
}

int TransitionLine::type() const {
  return Type;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PRIVATE SECTION                                                           //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void TransitionLine::createSubShapes() {
  m_controlAnchor = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(this);
  m_startControlLine = new QGraphicsLineItem(this);
  m_endControlLine = new QGraphicsLineItem(this);
  m_controlAnchor->setVisible(false);
  m_startControlLine->setVisible(false);
  m_endControlLine->setVisible(false);
  m_controlAnchor->setRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
  m_controlAnchor->setZValue(AnchorZValue);
}

void TransitionLine::drawArrow(QPainter* painter) {

}

void TransitionLine::setDefaultLineData() {
  auto b1 = static_cast<QGraphicsItem*>(m_startState)->sceneBoundingRect();
  m_startPoint = mapFromScene(findRectLineIntersection(m_startState->sceneBoundingRect(), m_endState->scenePos()));
  m_endPoint = mapFromScene(findRectLineIntersection(m_endState->sceneBoundingRect(), m_startState->scenePos()));
  m_firstControlPoint.rx() = 0.5 * (m_endPoint.x() - m_startPoint.x()) + m_startPoint.x();
  m_firstControlPoint.ry() = 0.5 * (m_endPoint.y() - m_startPoint.y()) + m_startPoint.y();
}

void TransitionLine::enableModifiers(bool enabled) {
  m_controlAnchor->setVisible(enabled);
  m_startControlLine->setVisible(enabled);
  m_endControlLine->setVisible(enabled);
  m_modifiersEnabled = enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    m_controlAnchor->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    m_controlAnchor->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
    m_controlAnchor->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges, true);
  }
}

QPointF TransitionLine::findRectLineIntersection(const QRectF& rect, const QPointF& p) const {
  bool validate = false;
  qreal x = p.x();
  qreal y = p.y();
  qreal minX = rect.x();
  qreal maxX = rect.x() + rect.width();
  qreal minY = rect.y();
  qreal maxY = rect.y() + rect.height();

  qreal midX = (minX + maxX) / 2;
  qreal midY = (minY + maxY) / 2;
  // if (midX - x == 0) -> m == ±Inf -> minYx/maxYx == x (because value / ±Inf = ±0)
  qreal m = (midY - y) / (midX - x);

  if (x <= midX) { // check "left" side
    qreal minXy = m * (minX - x) + y;
    if (minY <= minXy && minXy <= maxY)
      return QPointF(minX, minXy);
  }

  if (x >= midX) { // check "right" side
    qreal maxXy = m * (maxX - x) + y;
    if (minY <= maxXy && maxXy <= maxY)
      return QPointF(maxX, maxXy);
  }

  if (y <= midY) { // check "top" side
    qreal minYx = (minY - y) / m + x;
    if (minX <= minYx && minYx <= maxX)
      return QPointF(minYx, minY);
  }

  if (y >= midY) { // check "bottom" side
    qreal maxYx = (maxY - y) / m + x;
    if (minX <= maxYx && maxYx <= maxX)
      return QPointF(maxYx, maxY);
  }

  // edge case when finding midpoint intersection: m = 0/0 = NaN
  return QPointF(x, y);
}
```

Basically when I create the connector instead of start and end points I pass the pointers to two states.

When I drag a state I call a `mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)` in my `QGraphicsView` subclass, where I notice which is the state that's dragged, and then I call this method:

```
void Canvas::moveStateUnderMouse(QMouseEvent* event) {
  auto state = getStateUnderMouse(event);
  if (state != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "MOUSE IN STATE" << std::endl;
    viewport()->repaint();
  }
}
```

It works properly. I can see "MOUSE IN STATE" when I expect it, only when I select a state and I drag it with the mouse. But I don't find a way for telling here that also the connector should be updated. Since the connector has all needed data, since it stores state pointers, I've thinked that calling here only `viewport()->repaint()` is sufficient, but the connector remains still there.

What should I do in order to udpate the connector when one of connected states change the position?

Comment: I guess, the problem isn't that the connector is not repainted, but the points it connects aren't updated when you move your object. The connector still connect the old coordinates. Make sure you update the start and end points of your connector while dragging.

Comment: In `paint` event of connector I don't use coordinates. I've pointers to states and it retrieve new point data every time that paint is recalled.

Comment: What about `TransitionLine::m_startPoint`, `TransitionLine::m_endPoint`?

Comment: I think that it's the issue.. I've code for updating data but for some reason I don't call them. I'll check, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you take a look at Qt's Diagram Scene example, it is somewhat similar to your problem.

Instead of keeping a start point and an end point in your `TransitionLine` class, you should keep a pointer for each state connected by your line (in this case, a pointer for "Back" and a  pointer for "Right"), then implement an `adjust()` method ( or name it whatever you want), that recalculates the line between `state1->pos()` and `state2->pos()`, and finally call `update()`.

Then, in your `SimpleStateShape` class, you'll need to store a pointer to each connector and reimplement `itemChange`. It should look something like this:

```
QVariant SimpleStateShape::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, QVariant value) 
{
   if (change == ItemPositionHasChanged && !m_connectors.isEmpty()) {
       for (auto connector : m_connectors)
           connector->adjust();
   }

   QGraphicsObject::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

Of course, for this to work, you'll need to call `setFlag(ItemSendsGeometryChanges)` in the constructor of your `SimpleStateShape` class.